# Two functions intertwined by a conformal map: Functions are "conformally equivalent"?

Tags: notation

I asked this question earlier, but it was embedded in another non-notational [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/437598/conjecture-every-analytic-function-on-the-closed-disk-is-conformally-a-polynomi), so no replies have been directed to this notational question.  Thus I will ask it again here with the "notation" tag.

For analytic functions $f_1,f_2$ with domains $G_1,G_2\subset\mathbb{C}$ respectively, if there is a conformal map $\phi:G_1\to{G_2}$ such that $f_1\equiv{f_2}\circ\phi$ on $G_1$, then I would say $f_1$ and $f_2$ are conformally equivalent.

Is this the correct term?  If not, what is the correct term?  If so, is there any other term which is used for this relationship as well?

Comment: @40votes I see!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google search for the phrases [maps are conformally equivalent](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22maps+are+conformally+equivalent%22) and [conformally equivalent maps](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22conformally+equivalent+maps%22) shows that the term is used in the way you intended. I would probably use it myself.

You can also speak of *factorization*, saying that  the holomorphic function $f_1$ *factors* into the composition of a polynomial with conformal map. Can be shortened  to "P-factorization" if you have to use it many times.

I prefer to reserve the term "intertwined" (which appears in the title of your question) for a different relation, $\phi\circ f_1=f_2\circ \phi$.

Whichever term you pick, you should explain its meaning somewhere in your paper.

Comment: @ 40votes Thanks very much.